# Hide Question After Clicking "review question"

Tags: feature-request, support, review

When reviewing questions, there is a `review question` link underneath the post title. When you click it, it expands the question, but there is no way to hide it.

To hide it, you need to refresh the page, unless there is a button hidden somewhere.

Any plans on adding that functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry about it. Those old panels which still use the "review question" link will eventually be replaced with the new review tasks (where you can only review one post at a time). That method won't exist anymore, so there's no need to change it.

Comment: Ok thanks for the response